# Adding featured image to a new post using front-end form?

Tags: custom-post-types, php

Have a front-end form to create a post, Was only able to add text data to the new post (title, content, text-typed custom fields). I want to add a featured image to the new posts too.

It's a WordPress site and I use Avada theme. The custom post type is the Avada's default ***Portfolio*** post. But generalised answers would be very helpful too (please give some explanation on your code).

> Please add some code to my PHP code and the form so that it can save a featured image too.

So, Here's my php code in fuctions.php in my child-theme:

```
    if(isset($_POST['title'])){

    $custom_field_address1 = $_POST['address1'];

    $my_post = array(

    'post_title' => $_POST['title'],
    'post_content' => $_POST['description'],
        
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'post_type' => 'your_post_type_name',
    'meta_input' => array(
        'address1' => $custom_field_address1,
        )
    );
    
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);

    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'address1', $custom_field_address1, false );
    echo 'New Post Saved !';
    
    die;
    }
```

My front-end form:

```
<form method="post">
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Post Title:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">
</div>
    
    
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Post Description :</label>
      <textarea class="form-control"  name="description"></textarea>
</div>
      
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="address1">Address :</label>
      <input type="text" name="address1" id="address1">
</div>

<BR>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I made a complete revising. Wrote shorter codes and double-checked it before pasting it here.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

I'm not sure how to do it without ContactForm 7 plugin, but here's my past code on how to do it in CF7:

Assuming your file field is `[file your-file]`.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'my_cf7_save_featured_image', 10, 2 ); 

function my_cf7_save_featured_image( $instance, $result ) {
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );  

  // Get submission data instead of using $_POST
  $sub = \WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
  $data = $sub->get_posted_data();

  // Create post
  $my_post = array(
    'post_title' => $data['title'],
    'post_content' => $data['description'],
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'post_type' => 'post',
  );
    
  $post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
  add_post_meta( $post_id, 'address1', $data['address1'], false );
  
  // extract submitted file
  $uploaded_files = $sub->uploaded_files();
  $image_name = $data['your-file'];
  $image_location = $uploaded_files['your-file'];
  $image_content = file_get_contents( $image_location );

  // set upload path
  $dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $upload = wp_upload_bits( $image_name, null, $image_content );
  $filename = $upload['file'];
  
  $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );

  $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
  );

  // start upload and attach to post
  $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, wp_slash( $filename ), $post_id );

  // update image metadata
  $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, wp_slash( $filename ) );
  wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
}
```

Comment: I'd be glad if you give some explanation. I am very new to PHP and WordPress. Does it work on my code? I will try by I think I need explanation.

Comment: I used it in every way I could and it didn't work. Where exactly should I place this PHP code? 
CF7 code for addind image file: `[file my_cf7_save_featured_image]`

The submit button:
`[submit "wpcf7_submit"]`

Comment: Updated my answer. I thought your existing code already does the uploading. I copied my code from past project. There might be some typo in field name, but you can adapt from there.